# Android NDK for Ubuntu 14.04 32 Bit

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have searched a lot and even checked the link-https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html but not finding android NDK for Linux 32 Bit. Kindly help.

Comment: can anyone post an answer to this please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NDK is only available for 64 bit linux these days. I think NDK r10 is the last version that was available for 32 bit - you can download that from http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86.bin.

Comment: Thank you.If you could please help me with the steps to install the same as I extracted it to a folder and then added it to the path.But when i execute  ndk-build command, it always says command not found.

Comment: please help with installation

Comment: Let me know How you process these bin file in Android studio. I stuck how to use bin file